# Show different body background IMAGE based on selection

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I want that if you select a option in the select menu, that the background will change on the page

Can it also be done with a smooth fade out fade in animation?

[codepen](http://codepen.io/xcoder/pen/WvMGbJ)

```css
    body {
        background-image: url("http://www.manners.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Manners-stijlvolste-steden-londen-6.jpg");
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      
      <br><br><br>
      <select class="form-control select">
        <option> Show London Background Picture</option>
        <option> Show Paris Background Picture</option>
        <option> Show Italy Background Picture</option>
      
      </select>
      
      
      <br>
      <div class="jumbotron">
    IF LONDON SELECTED THEN BACKGROUND: <br>http://www.manners.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Manners-stijlvolste-steden-londen-6.jpg<br><br>
    IF PARIS SELECTED THEN BACKGROUND: <br>    
    http://travelnoire.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/eiffel-tower-paris-2.jpg<br><br>
    IF ITALY SELECTED THEN BACKGROUND: <br>
        https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Colosseum_in_Rome,_Italy_-_April_2007.jpg</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply an function to the onchange-event of your select-element which changes the background-image of your site:

```
$('#ID_OF_YOUR_SELECT').change(function() {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("' + this.value + '")');
});
```

Here is an updated codepen based on your example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNvapW

Comment: Thansk for yoiur help, but you deleted the value= " option here " .. So if i send the form i need to get the VALUE like value="this option" in my form,.. But now you paste the image into the value...

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Asgaros answer, I have added the fade in and out feature.

Here is the result: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wayzyx. The effect was done by adding a few lines of css to the body's css.

```
-webkit-transition: background 0.8s linear;
-moz-transition: background 0.8s linear;
-o-transition: background 0.8s linear;
transition: background 0.8s linear;
```

Comment: Thanks alot Yung! But can you make it Fade in and Fade out instead the linear?

Answer (score 0):

This changes the class of `body` and fades the background when the `select` value is changed.

```js
//set background based on default select value
$(document).ready(
  function() { changeBackground.call($('.form-control')); }
);

//change background when select value is changed
$('.form-control').change(function() {
  changeBackground.call($(this));
});

function changeBackground() {
  var $body = $('body');
  var values = "";
  this.children('option').each(function() {
    values += $(this)[0].value + " ";
  });
  var selectedValue = this[0].value;
  
  $body.removeClass(values.replace(selectedValue, ""));
  $body.addClass(selectedValue);
};
```

```css
body {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transition: background-image 500ms ease;
    transition: background-image 500ms ease;
}
body.london {
    background-image: url("http://www.manners.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Manners-stijlvolste-steden-londen-6.jpg");
}
body.paris {
    background-image: url("https://images.indiegogo.com/file_attachments/620900/files/20140602122905-paris.jpg?1401737345");
}
body.italy {
    background-image: url("http://www.liberty-int.com/Public/Italy-Signature-Slide5-Venice.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br>
  <select class="form-control select">
    <option value="london">Show London Background Picture</option>
    <option value="paris">Show Paris Background Picture</option>
    <option value="italy">Show Italy Background Picture</option>

  </select>


  <br>
  <div class="jumbotron">
IF LONDON SELECTED THEN BACKGROUND: <br>http://www.manners.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Manners-stijlvolste-steden-londen-6.jpg<br><br>
IF PARIS SELECTED THEN BACKGROUND: <br>    
http://travelnoire.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/eiffel-tower-paris-2.jpg<br><br>
IF ITALY SELECTED THEN BACKGROUND: <br>
    https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Colosseum_in_Rome,_Italy_-_April_2007.jpg
</div>
```