# Add background images in dropdown list in option

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add background images in option but it cannot work properly. How can i do?Thank you

```css
select #imge option[value="1"] {
  background-image: url(tree.png);
}
```

```html
<div id="ddls">
  <select id="imge" class="ddls">

    <option value="nothing"></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>

  </select>

</div>
```

Comment: <div id="ddls">
                    <select id="imge" class="ddls">
                            <option value="nothing"></option>
                            <option value="1" >1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                     </select> </div>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add background image for options in a select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207223/how-to-add-background-image-for-options-in-a-select-box)

Comment: @Connum if i select option 1 , it's going to display back ground image in body, not in option background

Comment: And how were we supposed to know that? ;)

Comment: @ connum does it cannot read it ?                                                              
               background-image: url(tree.png);

Comment: Why don't you create a custom dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `select2.js`.

Do check out the [GitHub link](https://select2.github.io/select2/)

Comment: @ Deepak Jain: Thank you, can we add if condition in select option. Example: if one dropdown having country list and one more dropdown having states .If i select India-second dropdown show states. If i select state it will show map of that state in body. I found one from -STACK OVER FLOW  but how to conent forst drop down with second dropdown https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162565/show-different-body-background-image-based-on-selection/56490604#56490604

Comment: I would suggest you to search for **"How to populate dropdowns"** on stackoverflow or on search engine. You'll for sure get a solution easily. Note: No condition required.

Comment: @ i added image in value(option), when i select option  image is repeating. How can i assign propertirs if i add image in value?Ty

Comment: I cannot help without checking out your code. But, do cross check whether you're iterating the option value within your loop.

Comment: <option value="img/new.png"">dog</option> ---i written like this

Comment: Is it under any loop or written as static? Please showcase the code properly.

Comment: it's not under any loop, but i written jquery to change image lengths $('#size').change(function(event){$('body').removeClass('cat  dog');
  
  $('body').addClass( 'flash-bar-size-' + $(this).val() );

Comment: I can't help out with the partial codes you're sharing. Second point, I'm confused why are you adding/removing class. I guess you are having concern with image URLs and you're playing with classes.

Comment: Actually  i having different images for different options. By selecting option from dropdown image going to change. I am trying to add background image for every option.

Comment: You may use the code as shared here..  

`<select>
            <option value="red">red</option>
            <option value="green">green</option>
            <option value="blue">blue</option>
        </select>
        <script>
            $('select > option').each(function(){
                var clr = $(this).attr('value');
                $(this).css('background-color', clr);
            });
        </script>`